# Matching only a non repeated occurrence of a character with Javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the asterisk character `*` but only when it occurs once.

I have tried:

```
/\*(?!\*)/g
```

Which checks ahead to see if the next character is **not** an asterisk. This gets me close, but I need to ensure that the previous character is also **not** an asterisk.  Unfortunately javascript does not support negative lookbehind.

To clarify:

```
This is an ex*am*ple
```

should match each asterisk, but:

```
This is an ex**am**ple
```

should not return any match at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to match only the asterisk character, or is extracting a group sufficient? Note that your attempt wouldn't work even if the syntax were supported.

Comment: I would like to match only the asterisk.  The attempt only checks forwards to see if the next character is an asterisk, but makes no attempt to check backwards, which is what I believe I need to do.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to do that with a single regex execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var r = /(^|[^*])(\*)([^*]|$)/;

r.test('This is an ex*am*ple');    // true
r.test('This is an ex**am**ple');  // false
r.test('*This is an example');     // true
r.test('This is an example*');     // true
r.test('*');                       // true
r.test('**');                      // false
```

In all cases, the matched asterisk is in capture group 2.

For a complete solution, not using regular expressions:

```
function findAllSingleChar(str, chr) {
   var matches = [], ii;

   for (ii = 0; ii < str.length; ii++) {
     if (str[ii-1] !== chr && str[ii] === chr && str[ii+1] !== chr) {
       matches.push(ii);
     }
   }

   return matches.length ? matches : false;
}

findAllSingleChar('This is an ex*am*ple', '*');   // [13, 16]
findAllSingleChar('This is an ex**am**ple', '*'); // false
findAllSingleChar('*This is an example', '*');    // [0]
findAllSingleChar('This is an example*', '*');    // [18]
findAllSingleChar('*', '*');                      // [0]
findAllSingleChar('**', '*');                     // false
```

Comment: thanks, I see that the best way to do this then in my case would be to match all occurrences of the asterisk and then check to see if the length is 1

Comment: Obviously, `findAllSingleChar` won't work if you're searching for NUL (`'\0'`);

Comment: Hmm, it seems going out of bounds on a string just returns `undefined`. In which case, the padding is unnecessary and `'\0'` will work just fine.